# Low UILocalNotification volume for some users, any way to control it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, notifications

We have an app that uses UILocalNotification for notifying the users about events at the background.

the problem is some of the users hears the background notifications at a very low volume.

When it does happen, the only way the user can "reset" the notification volume is via a device reboot. Once that is done it comes back to a normal level.

other ways that we have tried are by changing settings outside the app:

1. using the volume buttons- changed the iPod's volume or the ringer volume, did not effect notifications volume level.
2. setting in: settings->sounds->ringer and alerts->setting to highest. did not have any effect on the notifications volume.
3. changing the volume at the iPod player: did not effect the notification volume.
4. finally restarting the iPhone - did set the notifications volume to a normal level, but it's not a good solution for the customers.

We looked for a code solution for this issue and tried many different options:

1. changing the iPod volume ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]setVolume:1.0f])
   only changed the iPod's volume and did not worked on notifications.
2. tried using [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:NULL]; and then chaining the volume as in #1 - did not work.
3. using the volume slider "MPVolumeView" as is, this slider also did not seem to control notifications volume.

Is there a way that we can programmatically ensure that the notification volume is always at a normal audible level?

If not - what should we advise our users?  A reboot always fixes this, but its a poor solution to advise to a user.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dan's answer is correct, please select it as correct to let other know as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible,
You can't control the notifications volume with a costume UI slider.   Only the default slider provided by Apple.